# Python: File Not Found Error. No such file or directory named

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have to read a simple file named 'highscore.txt' in my slakes.py file.
**Both are located in same folder**.
But idk why I am getting file not found error
Code:

```
with open('highscore.txt', 'r') as f:
    high_score = f.read()
```

Comment: Are you running Python from the same folder as well? When reading a relative path, Python reads from the current working directory (not the script file).

Eg...

```
$ pwd 
/path/to/my/project

$ ls /path/to/my/project
./code

$ ls /path/to/my/project/code
./script.py
./highscores.txt

$ python ./code/script.py
FileNotFoundError [Errno 2] No such file or directory: highscores.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether the folder where the VS Code terminal is currently located is the parent folder of the python file being executed.

Solution:

1. You could use the command "`cd folder_name`" in the terminal to go to the parent folder of the python file:

   [image]
2. Or use the following settings in the settings file "[settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)":

   `"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true,`

   It will automatically go to the parent folder of the current file before executing the run command:

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using module named csv
The following code is a basic code to read a file:

```
    import csv
    with open('file directory') as F:
        reader = csc.reader(F)
        for row in reader:
            print (rows)
```

You can use any variables

Comment: Ok I will try but can you tell me why python is giving the error?

Answer (score 0):

This part of code check if `file` is exist. If not - create this empty file and read this file. 
I recommend using the full path to your file like `/home/user/folde/subfolder/file.txt` 
**I hope this helps you.**

```
from subprocess import call as subprocess_call
from os.path import isfile as file_exist
file = "/path/to/your/file"
if not file_exist(file):
    # create file if exist
    subprocess_call(["touch", file])
    subprocess_call(["chmod", "777", file])
with open(file, "r") as f:
     high_score = f.read()
```